# How can I join 2 strings a,b to C and later retrieve value of a,b using only C. No restrictions on input of a & b

Tags: python

```
a = input("enter str1") 

b = input("enter str2")

c=str1+(any delimited I use here runs in an edge case)+str2
```

Now later in my code's pipeline is there any way where I could get values of a,b from C itself? I tried using some delimiters, but since there's no restriction on input strings, I ran into some edge cases, did try solving this using base64 conversion, but please help me if there's an easier way.

Comment: Why are you making them a single string? Could you pass around a 2-tuple instead, for example?

Comment: Base64 sounds like a fine solution. Why do you not want to use it?

Comment: they're actually inputs to hadoop pipeline, two strings combine to make a folder name, (I cant set restrictions on input, could be any character on keyboard).
hence can't pass as a tuple.

later in the pipeline when I have to do some operations in hive, I'd need to get values of "a" and "b" again from the folder name (C) itself.

base64 conversion is what im using currently but I'm sure there might be another way to do it too.

Comment: you could still store the values of `a` and `b`, like `d = {c: (a,b)}` then look then up later

Comment: okay so I found another way to do it, appended the length of first string to the beginning followed by a specific delimiter,

a = input("enter str1") 
b = input("enter str2")

c = str(len(a))+".."+a+b
print(c)

Answer (score 1):

Option1: Combine them into a `list` or a `tuple` instead:

```
c = [a, b]
c = (a, b)
```

And only convert them to a single string when required.

Option 2: combine them but pass around the length of `a` as well:

```
c = (a+b, len(a))
```

You can then use the length of `a` to recover `a` and `b` later:

```
a = c[0][0:a]
b = c[0][a:]
```

I'd consider option 1 preferable here as (in my opinion) it's clearer what the intent is.

Comment: First option definitely the way to go here. You can just `join` if you want a single string from `c`

Comment: they're actually inputs to hadoop pipeline, two strings combine to make a folder name, (I cant set restrictions on input, could be any character on keyboard). hence can't pass as a tuple. later in the pipeline when I have to do some operations in hive, I'd need to get values of "a" and "b" again from the folder name (C) itself. base64 conversion is what im using currently but I'm sure there might be another way to do it too.

Answer (score 0):

If you use in 'C' string only 'A', 'B' and 'delimiter' strings:

```
delimiter = ";"

a = input("enter str1") 
b = input("enter str2")
c = "{}{}{}".format(a, delimiter, b)

d,e = c.split(delimiter)
```

Result:

```
>>> delimiter = ";"
>>> a = input("enter str1")
enter str1"first"
>>> b = input("enter str2")
enter str2"second"
>>> c = "{}{}{}".format(a, delimiter, b)
>>> c
'first;second'
>>> d,e = c.split(delimiter)
>>> d
'first'
>>> e
'second'
>>>
```

Comment: It doesn't error. It questions about which delimiter and data are you use. If you know that only one ';' will be used - you can do it without any problems.

Comment: This has an edge case where it'll fail. Like i said strings can be combination of any characters o nkeyboard, hence delimiters would have edge cases.

enter str1--> "weqq;"
enter str --> 2323

they're actually inputs to hadoop pipeline, two strings combine to make a folder name, (I cant set restrictions on input, could be any character on keyboard). hence can't pass as a tuple. later in the pipeline when I have to do some operations in hive, I'd need to get values of "a" and "b" again from the folder name (C) itself.

Comment: basically if a string input ends with semi-colon or any other delimiter that may be used, there'll be an edge case

Comment: Ok, I understand your problem, but without extra data, you can't do it. Maybe send 2 string and process them later?